# How to determine if a polynomial in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ is a factor/multiple of another

Tags: polynomials

I am doing some [CRC calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) for a networking class, and I would like to know how to determine if a simple polynomial is a factor/multiple of another.

supposedly in CRC error checking if $e(x) = g(x)$ or if $e(x)$ is a multiple of $g(x)$ then the error will go undetected , I checked the math in an online polynomial calculator and it seems correct,

[Calculation](http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=10000000100010001&den=10111&f=d&e=1&p=1)

$(1)$ $X^4 + X^2 + X^1 + 1$

$(2)$ $X^8 + X^4 + X^2 + 1$

$(3)$ $X^{16} + X^8 + x^4 + 1$

Is $(2)$  a multiple of $(1)$?

So, then $(3)$ would be a multiple and so on ... Well at least according to the way I'm doing it.

Comment: You have [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). Are you looking for some special family of polynomials?

Comment: By the way. It seems to be you are computing in in the field of coefficients $\mathbb{F}_2$. So, when running long division whenever you get an even number you put a zero. The rest is the same.

Comment: So what is your main question?

Comment: @Arashium The title and the first sentence of the post have a question, the same question.

Comment: is polynomial 2) a multiple of polynomial 1)

Comment: Are you looking for division modulu 2?

Comment: yes it is modulo2 division i am doing ,

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you may just note that for $n \ge 2$
$$
(x^4 + x^2 + x + 1)^{2^{n-2}}
=
x^{2^{n}} + x^{2^{n-1}} + x^{2^{n-2}} + 1.
$$

So not only the polynomial under (1) divides all others, but all others are a power of it.

This is of course because [in characteristic two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) we have $(a + b)^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2}$.